# Sencha Touch 2 Make Navigation Example map pannable

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can I make the map on the example given with Sencha Touch 2, the navigation view pannable:

Online example:

http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/examples/navigationview/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll get better Sencha answers on the sencha forums.

Here's an extension that does what you want.

https://github.com/SwarmOnline/Ext.ux.touch.MapLoader

Answer (score 0):

It's because above example set `mapOptions` that disable your `panControl`:

```
mapOptions: {
    zoomControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    rotateControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    zoom: 13
}
```

You can check out more about google map [options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)

Comment: I tried enabling everything, the pan elements do come onto the screen but they're not responsive to tapping/clicking.

By default the map control, even with `panControl:false` is still supposed to be pannable by touch, but the Google round pan up/down/left/right wont display